# Create a list with several slots

Tags: r

I'm a newbie to R and struggling to solve this, I also attached my code below. Can you please have a look and show me where I messed up?
Thank you!!

> Create a list of n slots, each slot contains two elements:
>
> 1. a line of n1,..., n100
> 2. a five-dimensional vector with elements following normal distribution with mean 23 and sd 5

[image]

Comment: Please post the code **as code** and format it properly (see the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). Do not post it as a picture. Additionally, the link you’ve posted isn’t publicly accessible (it’s a link to a resource on your local computer).

Comment: Judging by the look of it, the lengths of `vect` and `name` are not the same that's why it throws this warnings. One is `100` whereas the other is `5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
out <- lapply(1:100, function(x) rnorm(5, mean=23, sd=5))
out <- setNames(out, paste0('n', 1:100))
out[1:5]
#> $n1
#> [1] 31.43066 19.53338 23.65092 27.30282 23.80709
#> 
#> $n2
#> [1] 21.56448 20.87976 15.50641 22.20882 18.94148
#> 
#> $n3
#> [1] 29.73712 18.24457 18.71556 22.49429 18.73912
#> 
#> $n4
#> [1] 18.38924 28.40927 17.70546 23.67700 22.10596
#> 
#> $n5
#> [1] 30.31459 25.72874 25.87039 30.23306 23.21051
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replicate`

```
setNames(
  replicate(100, list(rnorm(5, mean = 23, sd = 5))),
  paste0("n", seq(100))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
x = list()
for(i in 1:100){
  nam = paste("N",i,sep = '')
  vec = rnorm(1000,3,10)
  x[[i]] = list(nam,vec)
}

x[[1]] ## slot 1
x[[2]] ## slot 2


## OR

x = list()
for(i in 1:100){
  nam = paste("N",i,sep = '')
  vec = rnorm(1000,3,10)
  x[[nam]] = vec
}

x[['N1']] ## slot 1
x[['N2']] ## slot 2
```